# Selecting with subqueries in MySQL (Subqueries with ANY, and IN)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

Thanks for the great answers!

**For More Information**

- [More info on MySQL IN comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)
- [Joining Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
- [Subqueries with ANY, IN, and SOME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

---

This is hard to explain, so lets set the stage...

```
userActions         userGroupMap
+------+--------+   +------+-------+
| user | action |   | user | group |
+------+--------+   +------+-------+
| x    | acted! |   | x    | a     |
| y    | acted! |   | y    | a     |
| y    | acted! |   | z    | b     |
| z    | acted! |   +------+-------+
| y    | acted! |
| z    | acted! |
| x    | acted! |
| z    | acted! |
+------+--------+
```

I want to select group a's actions. My idea was to

```
SELECT actions, user FROM userActions
    WHERE user = (SELECT user, group FROM userGroupMap WHERE group = a)
```

But obviously this subquery returns more than one row. Should I use a JOIN?

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is this:

```
SELECT actions,
       user
FROM   userActions
WHERE  user IN
               (SELECT user
               FROM    userGroupMap
               WHERE   [group] = 'a'
               );
```

However, with large tables, this query tends to be inefficient and doing a join is better:

```
SELECT actions,
       userActions.user
FROM   userActions
       INNER JOIN
              (SELECT user
              FROM    userGroupMap
              WHERE   [group] = 'a'
              ) AS tmp
       ON     userActions.user = tmp.user;
```

Alternatively, as Jonathon mentioned, you could have done this and its pretty much as efficient, if not more:

```
SELECT actions,
       userActions.user
FROM   userActions
       INNER JOIN userGroupMap
       ON     userActions.user = userGroupMap.user
WHERE  [group] = 'a';
```

Comment: Thank you! With your answer I got my results flawlessly. I also appreciate the note about large tables (Which is why I accepted your answer).
Can you elaborate on why you put group in brackets-"[group]"?

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this needs a sub-query; a straight inner-join with filtering WHERE clause should also do the job.

Comment: @Blaine: I put [group] in brackets because its a keyword and some DBMS freak out if keywords used as column/table names is not explicitly stated.  Same reason I'd put [table] in brackets.

@Jonathan Leffler:  You are right, I think I was just distracted by the question and it using subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT actions, user FROM userActions
    WHERE user IN (SELECT user FROM userGroupMap WHERE group = a)

SELECT actions, user FROM userActions
    WHERE user = ANY (SELECT user FROM userGroupMap WHERE group = a)
```

(Amended: only the user column should be returned, as noted by others.)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do something like:

```
SELECT 
  a.actions, 
  a.user 
FROM 
  userActions a 
  INNER JOIN userGroupMap g 
    ON a.user = g.user
WHERE
  g.group = 'a'
```

Comment: Yes; this works best in this situation.  But there is also the issue of 'how to deal with sub-queries that return multiple rows', and that is done with IN or = ANY or variants thereof.  But those queries can often be rewritten with a join instead of a sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this query will give you what you need:

```
SELECT actions, user 
FROM userActions 
WHERE user IN 
    (SELECT user FROM userGroupMap WHERE group = 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT actions, user FROM userActions
    WHERE user = (SELECT user FROM userGroupMap WHERE group = a)
```

The subquery was returning user and group (two fields) when it should be returning just user.

Comment: I agree that the sub-query was wrong in part because of the multiple columns; however, the question was about it returning more than one row, and your version still does that - and therefore fails at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use join than subquery:

```
SELECT
    userActions.action,
    userActions.user
FROM
    userActions
CROSS JOIN userGroupMap ON 
    userGroupMap.user = userActions.user AND
    userGroupMap.group = 'a'
```

Comment: On large tables, this will dramatically increase the size of the temporary table before cutting it down with group.  Its less efficient than joining on a subset of data.

Comment: What if put where statment in join ? Will that be better ?

Comment: No need for CROSS JOIN; use INNER JOIN (or just plain JOIN).

Comment: In MySQL, CROSS JOIN is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.